# Jenkins' email extension plugin messes up SMTP credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I'm trying to configure Jenkins' email extension plugin for quite a while now. First of all, the standard mailer works. Therefore, my credentials are correct.

But no matter what I choose from the credentials dropdown in the extended email section, I get the same error message (with debug enabled):

```
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: xxx@example.com yyy@example.com
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.example.com, user=jenkins, password=<null>
AuthenticationFailedException message: failed to connect, no password specified?
```

The username is not `jenkins` and there is a password set in the credentials.

Any ideas, anyone?

I've created the credentials with global scope and system scope, no difference. I've no clue how Jenkins comes up with these sort of default credentials.

Tested with email extension plugin version 2.104 and recent update to 2.105. The error persists.

Also, completely removing the credentials and recreating the entry in Jenkins did not cure the problem.

I'm running Jenkins 2.426.3.

There is nothing in the Jenkins logs with log level INFO.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same on Jenkins v2.425 with email extension v2.105.
Not a solution but maybe a temporary fix is to deactivate the authentication of your SMTP server and then remove the credentials.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).